# I have a query to get 2 things from my DB, but its getting everything. Someone knows what is wrong here?

Tags: node.js, api, sequelize.js

This is my query:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrCtg.png)

I'm using include and attributes to choose what I want:

```
const providers = await User.findAll({
  where: { provider: true },
  attributes: ['id', 'name', 'email', 'avatar_id'],
  include: [
    {
      model: File,
      as: 'avatar',
      attributes: ['name', 'path'],
    },
  ],
});
return res.json(providers);
```

Comment: can you plz add sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem once which I solved by using exclude, as include was not working properly in nested conditions you can try something like this

```
{
  model: File,
  as: 'avatar',
  attributes: { exclude: [/*Fields to exclude here */] }
}
```